# install ipk file from remote server

Tags: webos

how to install ipk file from remote server when user click on url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way with a stock webOS device.  In the homebrew world, the apps Preware and Internalz now support download and install for IPK files, but this is NOT supported without installing a homebrew app to alter the setup of the system.